# Vbox Kali Linux has no wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, virtualbox, kali-linux

I am running Kali 2.0 on virtualbox 5.0.12 with the extensions pack. My host is Windows 8.

At first I was having trouble getting the VM to see the TP-Link WN722N USB wireless card. I finally fixed that.

Now, however, I don't have any wireless connectivity. I've tried researching the problem, but haven't found anything helpful.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fS84a.jpg) is an album of lsusb, iwconfig, and ifconfig outputs. Sorry, I couldn't directly post the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.

cd into /etc/NetworkManager

edit NetworkManager.conf

Change the setting "managed=false" to "managed=true"

Then I was able to see wifi and connect.